# C++ ignoring warnings in a block with macro

Tags: c++, gcc, macros, pragma

I am using gcc 6.2 and want to ignore warnings in a macro. My idea was to do as in the following demo code.

```
typedef char aligned_char __attribute__((__aligned__));

// disable warning using #pragma at the beginning of the macro
// and enable it back at the end    

#define DISABLE_WARNING() \
   _Pragma ("GCC diagnostic push") \
   _Pragma ("GCC diagnostic ignored \"-Wignored-attributes\"")

#define ENABLE_WARNING() \
   _Pragma ("GCC diagnostic pop") \


#define MACRO() \
   DISABLE_WARNING() \
   A<aligned_char> a; \  << This will cause warning  
   a.print(); \
   ENABLE_WARNING()

template <typename T>
class A {
public:
    void print () {}
};

int main ()
{
    MACRO()
}
```

So when the macro expands we have the pragma to ignore the warning also. But seems like I am missing something here. Could someone please explain why it doesnt work.

If I use -save-temps option, then I see the warning is ignored and the pragmas are proper

```
g++ -save-temps -Wall tmp.cpp
```

But if I compile without  -save-temps

```
g++ -Wall tmp.cpp
```

I see the warning is not ignored.

```
tmp.cpp:14:19: warning: ignoring attributes on template argument ‘aligned_char {aka char}’ [-Wignored-attributes]
     A<aligned_char> a; \
                   ^
tmp.cpp:26:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘MACRO’
     MACRO()
     ^~~~~
```

Comment: I believe `-save-temps` is used to indicate that the files have been pre-processed, so the compiler does not bother rechecking the macros at compile time. It's supposed to be a way to save time on processing macros during compilation. Therefore it is the pre-processor that does not issue warnings, not the compiler

Comment: -save-temps, I believe saves the preprocessed and compiled outputs in .ii and .s files. It certainly compiles the file and the a.out created.